# EF4.1 Updating data with child that is ICollection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to update DB data using Entity Framework and ICollection child property.

And for the INSERT case, EF saves child data automatically, but it does not for Updating case.

So I made for updating manually, but I guess there is a way for updating automatically that just I don't know.

please review my code, and give me advice

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}   
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children{ get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

// Controller method for INSERT

```
public void InsertTest(){
    //generate new Parent Data with child
    Parent parent = new Parent() { 
        Name = "Nancy"
    };

    parent.Children.Add(new Child()
    {
        Name = "First Son"
    });

    parent.Children.Add(new Child()
    {
        Name = "Second Son"
    });

    var parentRepository = unitofwork.parentRepository;
    parentRepository.insert(parent); //context.Set<Parent>().Add(parent);
    unitofwork.Save();
    // it save child entity well
}
```

// Controller method for UPDATE

```
public void UpateTest()
{
    //generate new Parent Data with child
    Parent parent = new Parent()
    {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Nancy"
    };

    parent.Children.Add(new Child()
    {
        ID = 1,
        ParentID = 1,
        Name = "First Son Renamed"
    });

    parent.Children.Add(new Child()
    {
        ID = 2,
        ParentID = 1,
        Name = "Second Son"
    });

    // add new data
    parent.Children.Add(new Child()
    {
        Name = "Third Son"
    });

    var parentRepository = unitofwork.parentRepository;
    parentRepository.update(parent); //context.Set<Parent>().Attach(entityToUpdate); context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    unitofwork.Save();
    // it save parent data, but it does not change any for child data

    // *** To make work, I did like this, ***
    // var childRepository = unitofwork.childRepository;
    //foreach (Child c in parent.Children.ToList())
    //{
    //    if (c.ID < 1)
    //    {
    //        childRepository.update(c);
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        childRepository.insert(c);
    //    }
    //}

    //unitofwork.Save();

    // then it works.
}
```

Comment: i would say post your save/update methods, the POCOs and the controller methods don't provide enough clues about any potential problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't attaching the chosen directly and marking them as dirty, EF has no way of detecting they have changed without losing their original values from the database.

Either load the children from the database and inject values into them (useful especially if you also want to remove chosen no longer in the list) or  use the unit of work to mark attached chosen as modified after attaching them (less dB operations, however, won't remove existing children).

From your code I assume that the update() method is the one that marks the entities as dirty.